# Why is my text not in the centre with this program (HTML)?

Tags: html

I am currently trying to program my own snake game and wanted the title and actual game imagery to be in the center of the website. It did work until I tried inserting a button to restart the game which made everything malfunction. Even though I tried undoing all of my changes I cant seem to get the text be in the middle. Additionally the `gameOverMessage` is 1) not being hidden at all and 2) Does not have any of the stylistic changes I applied in my java script. I am a complete beginner at coding so any advice would be very much appreciated and valued!

Here is how I did the CSS script with all the relevant elements:

```css
#snakeboard {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 500px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: -1;
}

#gameOverMessage {
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center; 
    position: relative;
    font-size: 150px; 
    color:rgb(235, 28, 28);
    font-weight: bold;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

For my problem with the Game Over message I inserted the class = "hidden" and then removed this tag once the `has_game_ended` function is activated. However for some reason this does not register.

```html
<h1 class="h1">My own snakegame</h1>
<p class="p1">Score:</p>
<div id="score"></div> 
<canvas id="snakeboard" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<div id="gameOverMessage" class="hidden">
    Game Over!
</div>
```

Removing the "hidden" class

```js
function main() {
    changing_direction = false;
    clear_board();
    drawFood();
    drawSnake();
    move_snake();

    if (!has_game_ended()) {
        setTimeout(main, 200);
    } else {
        const gameOverMessage = document.getElementById("gameOverMessage");
        gameOverMessage.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to have more information so we could reproduce the problem. Take a look at how to include enough information to achieve a ["minimum reproducible example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

At minimum, it would be helpful to include some HTML too, as well as more  JavaScript to see the context of your logic and why it isn't doing what you expect.

Also, something funky happened with your `code tags`. You should edit your question so it's formatted correctly. The CSS should have its own block and random words are currently in code tags.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code and it seems to work totally fine from what I can tell.  All I did here was add the button to toggle the `hidden` class.

```js
function toggleHiddenClass(){
  document.querySelector('#gameOverMessage').classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

```css
#gameOverMessage {
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center; 
    position: relative;
    font-size: 150px; 
    color:rgb(235, 28, 28);
    font-weight: bold;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="toggleHiddenClass()">toggle hidden class</button>

<div id="gameOverMessage" class="hidden">
    Game Over!
</div>
```